# Totalling up ballot results

Tags: sql-server, count

I have a ballot where each voter gets 3 votes, choosing from 10 different candidates. Vote 1 is allocated 3 points, vote 2 gets 2 points and vote 3 gets 1 point.

I have the following SQL queries to total the number of points gained from each of the votes (so separate results for votes 1, 2 and 3).

What I need to do is put all these results together in a single table, but I'm not too sure where to start.

```
SELECT cn.cand_name, (count(vote_1) * 3) as vote_1 FROM candidate_votes cv Inner Join candidate_names cn ON cv.vote_1 = cn.cand_number GROUP BY cand_name;

SELECT cn.cand_name, (count(vote_2) * 2) as vote_2 FROM candidate_votes cv Inner Join candidate_names cn ON cv.vote_2 = cn.cand_number GROUP BY cand_name;

SELECT cn.cand_name, (count(vote_3) * 1) as vote_3 FROM candidate_votes cv Inner Join candidate_names cn ON cv.vote_3 = cn.cand_number GROUP BY cand_name;
```

I have the following results table:

```
Voter_number    Vote_1     Vote2      Vote3
123             cand_1     cand_3     cand_2
456             cand_2     cand_1     cand_3
789             cand_2     cand_3     cand_1
```

And the following candidate name table:

```
cand_number     cand_name
cand_1          Dave
cand_2          Sarah
cand_3          Nigel
```

So the results I'm looking for will look something like:

```
Candidate       Votes
Dave            6
Sarah           7
Nigel           5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT cn.cand_name
     , COALESCE(cv1.cnt_1,0)
     , COALESCE(cv2.cnt_2,0)
     , COALESCE(cv3.cnt_3,0)
     , 3*COALESCE(cv1.cnt_1,0) + 2*COALESCE(cv2.cnt_2,0)
       + 1*COALESCE(cv3.cnt_3,0) AS total
FROM candidate_names AS cn
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT vote_1 AS vote
           , COUNT(*) AS cnt_1
      FROM candidate_votes cv
      GROUP BY vote_1
    ) AS cv1
    ON cv1.vote = cn.cand_number
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT vote_2 AS vote
           , COUNT(*) AS cnt_2
      FROM candidate_votes cv
      GROUP BY vote_2
    ) AS cv2
    ON cv2.vote = cn.cand_number
  LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT vote_3 AS vote
           , COUNT(*) AS cnt_2
      FROM candidate_votes cv
      GROUP BY vote_3
    ) AS cv3
    ON cv3.vote = cn.cand_number
```

Comment: The most efficient query goes to ypercube

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT
    cn.cand_name, 
    count(cv1.vote_1) * 3 as vote_1, 
    count(cv2.vote_2) * 2 as vote_2, 
    count(cv3.vote_3) as vote_3
FROM
    candidate_names cn
    LEFT JOIN
    candidate_votes cv1 ON cv1.vote_1 = cn.cand_number
    LEFT JOIN
    candidate_votes cv2 ON cv2.vote_2 = cn.cand_number
    LEFT JOIN
    candidate_votes cv3 ON cv3.vote_3 = cn.cand_number
GROUP BY cn.cand_name;
```

This also allows you to add all votes

```
(count(cv1.vote_1) * 3) +
    (count(cv2.vote_2) * 2) +
    count(cv3.vote_3) as totalvotes
```

Edit: rows are being multiplied by the JOIN which is why it's wrong for cand2 and cand3

```
SELECT
    cn.cand_name, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN cv.vote_1 = cn.cand_number THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) as vote_1, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN cv.vote_2 = cn.cand_number THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) as vote_2, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN cv.vote_3 = cn.cand_number THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as vote_3
FROM
    candidate_names cn
    JOIN
    candidate_votes cv ON cn.cand_number IN (cv.vote_1, cv.vote_2, cv.vote_3)
GROUP BY cn.cand_name;
```

Comment: @Tom: I had an error in my multiply for the weighting. Try it now please

Comment: I'd noticed that and corrected it already... it still didn't give the correct results.

Comment: @Tom: well, "the results are wrong" doesn't help. There is no sample data and no indication what's wrong (values wrong? too many candidates?).

Comment: your method gives Dave=6, Sarah=8, Nigel=6

Comment: @gbn let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1208/discussion-between-tom-and-gbn)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  Candidate = n.cand_name,
  Votes = SUM(s.vote_weight)
FROM (
  SELECT
    cand_number = CASE x.weight
      WHEN 1 THEN Vote3
      WHEN 2 THEN Vote2
      WHEN 3 THEN Vote1
    END,
    vote_weight = x.weight
  FROM candidate_votes v
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) x (weight)
) s
  INNER JOIN candidate_names n ON s.cand_number = n.cand_number
GROUP BY n.cand_name
```