# Selecting Values from Table as Column Headers

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following structure:

```
ID  KEY     VALUE   SEQ
1   Amount  5       2   
1   Amount  4       1
1   Type    T1      2   
1   Type    T1      1
2   Amount  10      2   
2   Amount  5       1
2   Type    T2      2
2   Type    T2      1
```

I would like to create a query to get this:

```
ID  Amount  Type
1   5       T1
2   10      T2
```

As you can see there could be multiple combinations of (ID, Key) but  (ID, Key, Seq) is unique.

```
SELECT  T.ID, 
        T1.VALUE as Amount, 
        T2.VALUE as Type
FROM 
    (SELECT ID, MAX(SEQ) as MAXSEQ FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID) as T
    JOIN
        TABLE as T1
            ON T1.ID = T.ID
            AND T1.KEY = 'Amount'
            AND T1.SEQ = MAXSEQ
    JOIN
        TABLE as T2
            ON T2.ID = T.ID
            AND T2.KEY = 'Type'
            AND T2.SEQ = MAXSEQ
```

But I am getting results that I wasn't expecting

```
ID  Amount  Type

    1   5       T1
    1   4       T1
    1   10      T1
    1   5       T1
    2   10      T2
    2   5       T2
    2   4       T2
    2   5       T2
```

I already read this post but it doesn't apply to my case although it helps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619618/selecting-values-from-a-table-as-column-headers)

Any idea on who to fix this?

Comment: I'm getting the desired result, I think.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3e87/1  Am I mising something?

Comment: thanks for the comments Andrew.. You are using sql server on your example. I am using oracle

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  id, amount, type
FROM TABLE1
  natural join (SELECT ID, MAX(SEQ) as SEQ FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ID) 
pivot (
  max(VALUE) for key in ('Amount' as amount, 'Type' as type)
)
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/09f61/4)

Answer (score 0):

Something you are missing from [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619618/selecting-values-from-a-table-as-column-headers) is the `DISTINCT` keyword.

See also the explanation below [the query posted by ypercube](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12620825/263057). In fact, you are getting duplicates because you are joining a table on itself. Thus, rows will be mirrorred.

Your subquery should be:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT ID, MAX(SEQ) as MAXSEQ FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID) as T
```

Comment: not really. By grouping by id I will get the same effect as DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there was another column, that I didn't put in the question (to avoid giving out real data)which was affecting the results. The unique constraint was (ID, Key, Seq, Time) instead of (ID, Key, Seq).  As @Andrew Mentioned the query is returning the correct results.

Here goes the query again

```
SELECT  T.ID, 
        T1.VALUE as Amount, 
        T2.VALUE as Type
FROM 
    (SELECT ID, MAX(SEQ) as MAXSEQ FROM TABLE GROUP BY ID) as T
    JOIN
        TABLE as T1
            ON T1.ID = T.ID
            AND T1.KEY = 'Amount'
            AND T1.SEQ = MAXSEQ
    JOIN
        TABLE as T2
            ON T2.ID = T.ID
            AND T2.KEY = 'Type'
            AND T2.SEQ = MAXSEQ
```

Thanks Andrew for the clarification and the sqlfiddle. I apologize if I wasted anyone's time.